# Getting error 401 while trying to configure front end to work with api built in bootcamp

Tags: asp.net

I am currently attempting to utilize an API that I developed during a coding bootcamp last year. Although I am able to successfully retrieve data from the database using the API, I am facing an issue where my front end is receiving a 401 error when attempting to send requests to the API.

I am unsure of how to modify the security settings to resolve this issue. I am seeking suggestions on potential solutions or areas to investigate further.

Comment: dont know if anyone has an idea if this error is causing it:((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest)request).Form '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest)request).Form' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: figured it out, onto the next problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.